# How do I get beefalos into caves?

Tags: dont-starve

The wiki says you can get beefalos into caves.

I tryed with the beefalo horn, getting them to follow me into the cave, but they don't want to go down. Did I do it wrong? Is it impossible?

I am not using any dlcs.

Comment: Can you link to the page that says this?  If it's [this page](http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/Beefalo), it says it's a bug.

Comment: Oop, I missed that. It was the caving guide on the wiki, but this answers my question. If you put an answer, I'l accept it.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot get beefalos into caves, the [wiki page](http://dontstarve.wikia.com/wiki/Beefalo) says it is a bug.

(Credit to [Kyralessa](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/2831/kyralessa) for this, I am merely putting this in answer form because they still have not after months.)

Answer (score 0):

It worked fine for me. On Don't Starve ROG for ps3. Just had to carefully get a group over with the horn then wait until they are almost right there at the hole and havn't stopped following  yet. The first time I went down they didn't follow. I went back up and called them towards me again. There was only one or two this time, the others were heading back to their biome but they were very close to the hole this time and when I got down all 5 made it into the caves. They have a directive in the caves apparently maybe the same as where they came from above. So I'm still figuring out where they will settle and might make fence them off in a few areas down there until they settle.